# how to add string in dynamic array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, shopify

Here i got only id how can I modify to get (37398351478977: 1 ,42110385783015:1) string so i can add this in ajax for add to cart

```js
 var values=[];

    $(".ex_product_select").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
      values.push($(this).val());
    else{
      var x = values.indexOf($(this).val());
      values.splice(x,1) ;
    }
    $(".hide_extra_variant").text(values);
    });
 $(document).on("click",".add",function(){ 
   jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {  updates: {  values } });
  });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   

 Product1 : <input type="checkbox" class="ex_product_select" style="display:inline-block;" name="exselect" value="37398331392193">
        Product2 : <input type="checkbox" class="ex_product_select" style="display:inline-block;" name="exselect" value="37398351478977">
        Product3 : <input type="checkbox" class="ex_product_select" style="display:inline-block;" name="exselect" value="42110385783015">

<button class="add" value="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>

     <p class="hide_extra_variant"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this result?

```js
var values=[];

    $(".ex_product_select").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
      values.push({key:values.length+1,value:$(this).val()});
    else{
      var x = values.findIndex(x => x.value == $(this).val());
      values.splice(x,1) ;
    }
    
    console.clear();
    
    console.log(values)
    
    let allValues = "(" + values.map(x => x.value + ":1").join() + ")";
    
    $(".hide_extra_variant").text(allValues);
    });
 $(document).on("click",".add",function(){ 
   jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {  updates: {  values } });
  });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   

 Product1 : <input type="checkbox" class="ex_product_select" style="display:inline-block;" name="exselect" value="37398331392193">
        Product2 : <input type="checkbox" class="ex_product_select" style="display:inline-block;" name="exselect" value="37398351478977">
        Product3 : <input type="checkbox" class="ex_product_select" style="display:inline-block;" name="exselect" value="42110385783015">

<button class="add" value="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>

     <p class="hide_extra_variant"></p>
```

Comment: yes exactly i want to use jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {  updates: {    794864053: 2,   794864233: 3  }}); this but its not working i think i need to convert it to object

Comment: i dont know how to convert array variable into object for this code can you help me

Comment: I edit my code, can you check it?

Comment: it is showing https://prnt.sc/aiCoSDCNM0-a update js error

Comment: {"status":404,"message":"Cart Error","description":"Cannot find variant"}

Comment: Can you show where you post it ?

Comment: I used this on test store for practice got perfect output but add to cart is not working

Comment: I dont understand what kind of object do you want

Comment: I made 3 product which have 3 individual checkbox and one container which store  all selected products Id if use select 2 product and click to add to cart both items will go to cart  so here I used array for storing checkbox value but update js don't allow it it must have object instead of array to use jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', { updates: { 794864053: 2, 794864233: 3 }}) this js for add to cart